# How to determine Image of function?

Tags: functions

I am trying to solve this problem, but for some reason I cant seem to get it.

$ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad for \quad f(x) = x^2 - x - 3\cdot |x|$

I am supposed to find the Image of the function.

Any ideas?

Comment: What were your thoughts? What did you try? If you need help with why your approach did not lead to an answer, give your approach. If you want to know the answer to check if you got it right, [Wolfram Alpha has it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=image+f%28x%29%3Dx%5E2-x-3%7Cx%7C&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22image%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22DomainAndRangeWord%22%7D). Additionally, is the tag `complex-numbers` relevant, you write $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Let me suggest you take a look at our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [avoiding "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: You will want to note the absolute value in particular, as it denotes a piecewise function in disguise. You will want to examine the cases $x\lt 0$, $x\gt 0$ and $x=0$ (that one is easy) and the effects they have on the overall function, using the definition of absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, if $x\lt0$, then $|x|=-x$. So if $x\lt0$, then $f(x)=x^2-x-3(-x)=x^2+2x$. This part of $f(x)$ is an upward-opening parabola, meaning that it attains a minimum; this can be found by differentiating $f(x)$, setting it equal to $0$ and solving for $x$. The derivative of $f(x)$ in this region is $2x+2$; setting this equal to $0$ leads to $x=-1$. The value of $f(-1)$ is $(-1)^2+2(-1)=1-2=-1$. The image of $f(x)$ for $x\lt 0$ is therefore $[-1,\infty)$.

If $x\ge0$, then $|x|=x$. This means that for $x\ge0$, $f(x)=x^2-x-3x=x^2-4x$. As in the previous case this represents an upward-opening parabola, and so the minimum is given by $2x-4=0 \Rightarrow x=2$. The value of $f(2)$ is equal to $2^2-2-3(2)=4-8=-4$. The image of $f(x)$ in this part of the domain is therefore $[-4,\infty)$.

Now we want the image of $f(x)$, which is the set of all values it can attain. In the first case we found that $f(x)$ can be equal to any real number equal to or greater than $-1$, while in the second we found that it could be equal to any number greater than or equal to $-4$. The interval $[-1,\infty)$ is in fact a subinterval of $[-4,\infty)$, so this will be your answer.

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions that do not meet [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).